Azure Devops Storage - dataService undefined
I'm following on from the various examples on the microsoft website for devepos extensions, but the one for creating and editing documents does not seem to work for me (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops)
window.requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        'SDK': './lib/SDK.min',
    }
});

window.requirejs(['SDK'], function (SDK) {
    if (typeof SDK !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("SDK is defined. Trying to initialize...");
        SDK.init();
        SDK.ready().then(() => {
            console.log("SDK is ready");
            // Get data service
            SDK.getService(SDK.getContributionId()).then(function (dataService) {
                // Prepare document first
                var newDoc = {
                    fullScreen: false,
                    screenWidth: 500
                };

                dataService.createDocument("MyCollection", newDoc).then(function (doc) {
                    // Even if no ID was passed to createDocument, one gets generated
                    console.log("Doc id: " + doc.id);
                });
            });

        });
    } else {
        console.log('SDK is not defined');
    }
});

After calling SDK.getService, dataService is always undefined. As far as I can tell, the SDK has initialised correctly because many of the other SDK functions seem to work as expected, and the contributionID is correct. But I don't want to rule that out as a cause since I had a lot of trouble getting rid of the 'No handler found on any channel for message:' error.
Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

I noticed that there is a public repo where the author created an extension to get a document from collection, you can check if it's helpful for you. At the same time, you can try this sample in the official doc.

Hi Ziyang, thanks for your comment. Using the API to get the documents I can do, but unless I'm mistaken the API cannot create or write to the documents - this must be done using the SDK.
The code I've used above is a direct copy of the sample in the official documentation, so I can only assume I'm missing something rather obvious, unless there is something wrong with the sample on the microsoft website.

Checking the public repo shared before, it updates the document using updateDocumentByName(). I have tried to use the sample in the official doc to build an extension, but it failed with some errors like ReferenceError: define is not defined. I noticed some others had the similar issue with dataService. For example, this and this.

Hi Ziyang, the repo linked by maasha in this link that you provided appears to work.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/13803
Thank you!

Hi @cob, it's great to know it works for you. To help others who may have the similar question, I post an answer below to make it clearer.

I noticed some others had the similar issue with dataService. There is a repo  which seems to be working. Hope it's helpful for you.
    private async initializeState(): Promise<void> {
        await SDK.ready();
        const accessToken = await SDK.getAccessToken();
        const extDataService = await SDK.getService<IExtensionDataService>(CommonServiceIds.ExtensionDataService);
        this._dataManager = await extDataService.getExtensionDataManager(SDK.getExtensionContext().id, accessToken);

        this._dataManager.getValue<string>("test-id").then((data) => {
            this.setState({
                dataText: data,
                persistedText: data,
                ready: true
            });
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
                dataText: "",
                ready: true
            });
        });
    }

